# httpd.conf virtual host not working

Tags: php, apache, macos, mamp

I've added this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName dietron
    DocumentRoot /Users/kieransenior/Development/reformsoft_dietron/trunk/var/www/dietron/htdocs

    <Directory /Users/kieransenior/Development/reformsoft_dietron/trunk/var/www/dietron/htdocs>
        AllowOverride All
        Options All
    </Directory>

    php_value include_path .:/Users/kieransenior/Development/reformsoft_dietron/trunk/var/www/dietron/include:/usr/local/lib/pear
    php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_value register_globals off
</VirtualHost>
```

to my httpd.conf in the hope that my .htaccess file in the htdocs folder will be picked up with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

That is the entire contents.  I'm renaming .htaccess on my MBP by doing `mv i.htaccess .htaccess` which I'm assuming is correct?  I'm using MAMP therefore the httpd.conf has a load of default settings and I added the first snippet above at the very end of it.  I'm then restarting it by stopping Apache and starting it again.  The index.php gets picked up fine, however when I do `http://localhost:8888/anythinghere` it comes up with a 404, which shouldn't happen.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**: [Here's my httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/m563537b1)

**EDIT**: Here's the error in the Apache log:

```
[Fri Jun 05 16:02:22 2009] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Users/kieransenior/Development/reformsoft_dietron/trunk/var/www/dietron/htdocs/testing
```

Comment: Have you checked your apache logs? you can also set RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel to see what's going on. but these two directives has to go into you vhost, not the .htaccess file.

Comment: I duplicated this config on my machine and it works OK. Did you check the error log for clues?

Comment: Which and where is the error log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of suggestions.

First, on line 461 of your httpd.conf:

```
AccessFileName afn.htaccess
```

Shouldn't that be .htaccess?

The second thing I see is that the server name is set:

```
ServerName dietron
```

but you're trying to access it with localhost

I'd suggest that you put an entry in your /etc/hosts file so that dietron resolves, either to your local ip address or your loopback (127.0.0.1), and then access the server with http://dietron:8888

Comment: That's what I get for staring at httpd.conf all day.  Thankyou sir.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your AllowOverride directive is set properly at a global level. If no override is allowed (`AllowOverride None`) at your webroot, then your htaccess file will be ignored.

Comment: I've provided a link to my actual httpd.conf located in Applications/MAMP/conf/Apache/

Comment: Your `NameVirtualHost` directive value needs to match your virtual host config:

NameVirtualHost *:888
<VirtualHost *:8888>
   ...
</VirtualHost>

See if that solves the whole problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either.  Perhaps I should actually install Apache and MySQL locally as opposed to using MAMP?  That way I have more control over it.

Comment: For the purposes of config, if you have access to your httpd.conf, you have full access to Apache. I ended up using the MacPorts version, myself, but for other reasons. You already have full access to the configuration.  I did notice a typo in my comment above, if you didn't catch it: NameVirtualHost *:8888 (4 8's, not 3).